# Using numpy. binary_repr on array of numbers or alternatives - Python

Tags: python, numpy, binary

**using the following code i am trying to convert a list of numbers into binary number but getting an error**

```
import numpy as np

lis=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
a=np.binary_repr(lis,width=32)
```

the error after running the program is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 4, in 
>       a=np.binary_repr(lis,width=32)
>
> File "C:\Users.......",
>   in binary_repr
>       if num == 0:
>
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

**any way to fix this?**

Comment: `np.binary_repr` works on a single value, not on an array-like object.

Comment: i know that .but is there any way to make it work in an array ..?

Comment: or is there any code in python whereby i can convert my whole array or list into binary 32 bit?

Comment: Are you looking to get a string output or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) to overcome this issue.

```
>>> lis=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
>>> a=np.binary_repr(lis,width=32)
>>> binary_repr_vec = np.vectorize(np.binary_repr)
>>> binary_repr_vec(lis, width=32)
array(['00000000000000000000000000000001',
       '00000000000000000000000000000010',
       '00000000000000000000000000000011',
       '00000000000000000000000000000100',
       '00000000000000000000000000000101',
       '00000000000000000000000000000110',
       '00000000000000000000000000000111',
       '00000000000000000000000000001000',
       '00000000000000000000000000001001'], dtype='<U32')
```

Answer (score 3):

As the [documentation on **`binary_repr`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.binary_repr.html) says:

> `num : int`
>
> Only an **integer decimal number** can be
>   used.

You can however *vectorize* this operation, like:

```
np.vectorize(np.binary_repr)(lis, 32)
```

this then gives us:

```
>>> np.vectorize(np.binary_repr)(lis, 32)
array(['00000000000000000000000000000001',
       '00000000000000000000000000000010',
       '00000000000000000000000000000011',
       '00000000000000000000000000000100',
       '00000000000000000000000000000101',
       '00000000000000000000000000000110',
       '00000000000000000000000000000111',
       '00000000000000000000000000001000',
       '00000000000000000000000000001001'], dtype='<U32')
```

or if you need this often, you can store the vectorized variant in a variable:

```
binary_repr_vector = np.vectorize(np.binary_repr)
binary_repr_vector(lis, 32)
```

Which of course gives the same result:

```
>>> binary_repr_vector = np.vectorize(np.binary_repr)
>>> binary_repr_vector(lis, 32)
array(['00000000000000000000000000000001',
       '00000000000000000000000000000010',
       '00000000000000000000000000000011',
       '00000000000000000000000000000100',
       '00000000000000000000000000000101',
       '00000000000000000000000000000110',
       '00000000000000000000000000000111',
       '00000000000000000000000000001000',
       '00000000000000000000000000001001'], dtype='<U32')
```

Answer (score 3):

**Approach #1**

Here's a vectorized one for an array of numbers, upon leveraging [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
def binary_repr_ar(A, W):
    p = (((A[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(W-1,-1,-1)))!=0)).view('u1')
    return p.astype('S1').view('S'+str(W)).ravel()
```

Sample run -

```
In [67]: A
Out[67]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [68]: binary_repr_ar(A,32)
Out[68]: 
array(['00000000000000000000000000000001',
       '00000000000000000000000000000010',
       '00000000000000000000000000000011',
       '00000000000000000000000000000100',
       '00000000000000000000000000000101',
       '00000000000000000000000000000110',
       '00000000000000000000000000000111',
       '00000000000000000000000000001000',
       '00000000000000000000000000001001'], dtype='|S32')
```

**Approach #2**

Another vectorized one with array-assignment -

```
def binary_repr_ar_v2(A, W):
    mask = (((A[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(W-1,-1,-1)))!=0))
    out = np.full((len(A),W),48, dtype=np.uint8)
    out[mask] = 49
    return out.view('S'+str(W)).ravel()
```

Alternatively, use the mask directly to get the string array -

```
def binary_repr_ar_v3(A, W):
    mask = (((A[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(W-1,-1,-1)))!=0))
    return (mask+np.array([48],dtype=np.uint8)).view('S'+str(W)).ravel()
```

Note that the final output would be a view into one of the intermediate outputs. So, if you need it to have it own memory space, simply append with `.copy()`.

---

Timings on a large sized input array -

```
In [49]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: A = np.random.randint(1,1000,(100000))
    ...: W = 32

In [50]: %timeit binary_repr_ar(A, W)
    ...: %timeit binary_repr_ar_v2(A, W)
    ...: %timeit binary_repr_ar_v3(A, W)
1 loop, best of 3: 854 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 14.5 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 7.33 ms per loop
```

From other posted solutions -

```
In [22]: %timeit [np.binary_repr(i, width=32) for i in A]
10 loops, best of 3: 97.2 ms per loop

In [23]: %timeit np.frompyfunc(np.binary_repr,2,1)(A,32).astype('U32')
10 loops, best of 3: 80 ms per loop

In [24]: %timeit np.vectorize(np.binary_repr)(A, 32)
10 loops, best of 3: 69.8 ms per loop
```

On [`@Paul Panzer's solutions`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57837615/) -

```
In [5]: %timeit bin_rep(A,32)
548 µs ± 1.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit bin_rep(A,31)
2.2 ms ± 5.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thx for the timings.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fast method using `np.unpackbits`

```
(np.unpackbits(lis.astype('>u4').view(np.uint8))+ord('0')).view('S32')
# array([b'00000000000000000000000000000001',
#        b'00000000000000000000000000000010',
#        b'00000000000000000000000000000011',
#        b'00000000000000000000000000000100',
#        b'00000000000000000000000000000101',
#        b'00000000000000000000000000000110',
#        b'00000000000000000000000000000111',
#        b'00000000000000000000000000001000',
#        b'00000000000000000000000000001001'], dtype='|S32')
```

More general:

```
def bin_rep(A,n):
    if n in (8,16,32,64):
        return (np.unpackbits(A.astype(f'>u{n>>3}').view(np.uint8))+ord('0')).view(f'S{n}')
    nb = max((n-1).bit_length()-3,0)
    return (np.unpackbits(A.astype(f'>u{1<<nb}')[...,None].view(np.uint8),axis=1)[...,-n:]+ord('0')).ravel().view(f'S{n}')
```

Note: special casing n = 8,16,32,64 is absolutely worth it since it gives a severalfold speedup for these numbers.

Also note that this method maxes out at 2^64, larger ints require a different approach.

Comment: Is it generalizable to generic window lengths? Are there restrictions to the extents of the number values?

Comment: @Divakar Well, it is with some work ;-) And obviously beyond uint64 it is getting hairy.

Comment: Looks promising and obviously a smart one keeping those aside.

Comment: @Divakar I added a general version. Didn't try to handle ints >= 2^64, though. It is quite a bit slower for non-aligned sizes but still pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [193]: alist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

`np.vectorize` is convenient, but not fast:

```
In [194]: np.vectorize(np.binary_repr)(alist, 32)                                                            
Out[194]: 
array(['00000000000000000000000000000001',
       '00000000000000000000000000000010',
       '00000000000000000000000000000011',
        ....
       '00000000000000000000000000001001'], dtype='<U32')
In [195]: timeit np.vectorize(np.binary_repr)(alist, 32)                                                     
71.8 µs ± 1.88 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

plain old list comprehension is better:

```
In [196]: [np.binary_repr(i, width=32) for i in alist]                                                       
Out[196]: 
['00000000000000000000000000000001',
 '00000000000000000000000000000010',
 '00000000000000000000000000000011',
...
 '00000000000000000000000000001001']
In [197]: timeit [np.binary_repr(i, width=32) for i in alist]                                                
11.5 µs ± 181 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

another iterator:

```
In [200]: timeit np.frompyfunc(np.binary_repr,2,1)(alist,32).astype('U32')                                   
30.1 µs ± 1.79 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: For small arrays that is indeed the case, for larger arrays, like `lis = np.arange(1000)`, one sees that the list comprehension usually takes two times as much time. The `frompyfunc`, takes approximately 10% more time. This is not that strange, since numpy is definitely not a good idea for small amounts of data, it only pays off if you process data "in bulk".